# android app with twitter

Tags: android, twitter

I have a little experience with android, but now I am try to do a android app with twitter, I am trying to do something easy, for example show all trends near my location.

I read the Streaming API of twitter I think is the most appropiate to do this work, but I am a little losing, any idea, any examples? something to start.

Thanks

Comment: Don't misunderstand me,I looked for in google but I didn't find nothing like I wanted or something similar.
I just wanted to know if anyone knew of documentation about
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something as simple as showing the trends you won't need the streaming API at all. There's the REST API for this. You really just need your woeid, a json parser and being able to do http calls. For the complete documentation for trends from twitter I'd like to redirect you to the following link [https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/trends/%3Awoeid](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/trends/%3awoeid). From there you can find a lot more on the twitter API.